# New element is getting created even after unref of pipeline in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am trying to access appsink element to capture intermediate frames, and I have written a stream pipeline but when I change and start a new pipeline, I use gst_object_unref(pipeline, NULL) and set its state to NULL. But still when I check my pipeline instead of getting an element appsink0, I get appsink1 and after every start of new pipeline its keeps on incrementing for example.
First pipeline i started : it has elements as v4l2src0, appsink0
Second pipeline i started after unref of first pipeline : it has elements as v4l2src1, appsink1
third pipeline i started after unref of second pipeline : it has elements as v4l2src2, appsink2.
How to resolve this issue? Is it a pipeline issue or issue in gstreamer code?
I am using static pipeline.

The following things I have tried :
Using unref api from gstreamer : gst_object_unref(pipeline)
Setting state to NULL : pipeline = NULL && gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_OBJECT_NULL)

I am expecting elements to start with 0 for example appsink0, v4l2src0 after unref the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements usually get named with a ever increasing count whenever they are being created. This carries over across different pipelines. Use the `name` property of elements to give them a more "predictable" name.